I am trying PubSub API but I cannot publish event
I followed this guide Java Quick Start for Publishing and Subscribing to Events, currently on step 4. For executing bash scripts I installed cygwin terminal.
After I run:
bash run.sh genericpubsub.PublishStream
I received:
$ bash run.sh genericpubsub.PublishStream
2024-07-22 15:55:49,980 [main] java.lang.Class - Using grpcHost api.pubsub.salesforce.com and grpcPort 7443
2024-07-22 15:55:50,318 [main] java.lang.Class - sending request for xClientTraceId 2534e2b4-7d0a-4b33-8832-a8d2faff7a15
2024-07-22 15:55:52,529 [main] java.lang.Class - request completed for xClientTraceId 2534e2b4-7d0a-4b33-8832-a8d2faff7a15 with status Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=The topic information for org CORE/prod/00D9b000007rba5 and topic /event/Actico__Example_event_for_the_Pub_Sub_API_client__e is unavailable. Try again later. rpcId: 3b2ffa53-4959-b49c-9b7b-cabde4677c71, cause=null}
2024-07-22 15:55:52,535 [main] java.lang.Class - Error during fetching topic
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: The topic information for org CORE/prod/00D9b000007rba5 and topic /event/Actico__Example_event_for_the_Pub_Sub_API_client__e is unavailable. Try again later. rpcId: 3b2ffa53-4959-b49c-9b7b-cabde4677c71
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:268)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:249)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:167)
        at com.salesforce.eventbus.protobuf.PubSubGrpc$PubSubBlockingStub.getTopic(PubSubGrpc.java:587)
        at utility.CommonContext.setupTopicDetails(CommonContext.java:138)
        at genericpubsub.PublishStream.<init>(PublishStream.java:46)
        at genericpubsub.PublishStream.main(PublishStream.java:245)
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class - Error During PublishStream
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class -  === GRPC Exception ===
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: The topic information for org CORE/prod/00D9b000007rba5 and topic /event/Actico__Example_event_for_the_Pub_Sub_API_client__e is unavailable. Try again later. rpcId: 3b2ffa53-4959-b49c-9b7b-cabde4677c71
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:268)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:249)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:167)
        at com.salesforce.eventbus.protobuf.PubSubGrpc$PubSubBlockingStub.getTopic(PubSubGrpc.java:587)
        at utility.CommonContext.setupTopicDetails(CommonContext.java:138)
        at genericpubsub.PublishStream.<init>(PublishStream.java:46)
        at genericpubsub.PublishStream.main(PublishStream.java:245)
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class -  === Trailers ===
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class - [Trailer] = date [Value] = Mon, 22 Jul 2024 13:55:52 GMT
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class - [Trailer] = content-type [Value] = application/grpc
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class - [Trailer] = rpc-id [Value] = 3b2ffa53-4959-b49c-9b7b-cabde4677c71
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class - [Trailer] = error-code [Value] = sfdc.platform.eventbus.grpc.topic.api.unavailable
2024-07-22 15:55:52,548 [main] java.lang.Class - [Trailer] = type [Value] = GetTopic


The error message says: The topic information is unavailable for the specified topic.
But from this I dont know where could be the issue. Please help
